# SparkSQL subquery and performance

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In order to allow users of the system dynamically create(via application web UI) different data dictionaries with auxiliary data, I use DataFrames and expose them as temp tables, for example:

```
Seq("Italy", "France", "United States", "Spain").toDF("country").createOrReplaceTempView("big_countries")
Seq("Poland", "Hungary", "Spain").toDF("country").createOrReplaceTempView("medium_countries")
```

The number of these dictionaries is only limited by the user imagination and business needs.

After that users also create different queries which may use conditions based on the previously defined auxiliary data, for example SQL `WHERE` conditions:

```
Q1: country IN (FROM medium_countries)
Q2: (TRUE = ((country IN (FROM medium_countries)) AND (country IN (FROM big_countries))) AND EMAIL IS NOT NULL) AND phone = '+91-9111999998'
Q3: TRUE = ((country IN (FROM medium_countries)) AND (country IN (FROM big_countries))) AND EMAIL IS NOT NULL
......
Qn: name = 'Donald' AND email = 'donald@example.com' AND phone = '+1-2222222222'
```

The number of these queries is only limited by the user imagination and business needs.

My biggest worry right now is the subquery like `country IN (FROM medium_countries)`

I can't use explicit `JOIN` here according to the system design so I limited to use subqueries. So I have a question - typically the size of these auxiliary data tables should be relatively small... I think a few thousand rows in the worst case and the total number of these tables  - a few hundred in the worst case. Taking this into account, can this approach lead to the performance issue and is there any technics exist that can optimize the process, like caching these dictionaries in memory and so on?

**UPDATED**

Right now I can test it only in Spark Local Mode

Query:

```
country IN (FROM big_countries)
```

Execution plan:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+
|plan                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |tag|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+
|== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [unique_id#27L]
+- *(1) BroadcastHashJoin [country#22], [country#3], LeftSemi, BuildRight
   :- *(1) Project [country#22, unique_id#27L]
   :  +- LocalTableScan [name#19, email#20, phone#21, country#22, unique_id#27L]
   +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, string, true]))
      +- LocalTableScan [country#3]|big|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+
```

Query:

```
TRUE = ((country IN (FROM medium_countries)) AND (country IN (FROM big_countries))) AND EMAIL IS NOT NULL
```

Execution plan:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+
|plan                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |tag|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+
|== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [unique_id#27L]
+- *(1) Filter (true = (exists#53 && exists#54))
   +- *(1) BroadcastHashJoin [country#22], [country#3], ExistenceJoin(exists#54), BuildRight
      :- *(1) BroadcastHashJoin [country#22], [country#8], ExistenceJoin(exists#53), BuildRight
      :  :- *(1) Project [country#22, unique_id#27L]
      :  :  +- *(1) Filter isnotnull(EMAIL#20)
      :  :     +- LocalTableScan [name#19, email#20, phone#21, country#22, unique_id#27L]
      :  +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, string, true]))
      :     +- LocalTableScan [country#8]
      +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, string, true]))
         +- LocalTableScan [country#3]|big|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+
```

Comment: Could you post Physical execution plan of the dataframe? Output of the Dataframe.explain.

Comment: Sure, updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that:

```
CACHE TABLE tbl  as in sql("CACHE TABLE tbl")
```

is what you need to be executed after your:

```
...createOrReplaceTempView....
```

but before the larger queries of course.

In SPARK now, the above statement on "caching" is now eager by default, not lazy. As the manual states you don’t need to trigger cache materialization manually anymore. That is to say, no longer the need to execute a df.show or df.count.

Once in memory - the until you refresh explicitly, this data need not be gotten every time again and here it looks like no filtering, rather just load all the limited set of data once.

Not knowing your design but looking at it, the sub-query should be fine. Try this approach and look at the Physical Plan. In traditional RDBMS's, this type of limited sub-query - from what I can see - is also not a deal breaker.

You can also see that the Physical Plan shows the Catalyst Optimizer has optimized / converted your IN sub-query already to a JOIN, a typical performance improvement for larger data sets.

As a result "broadcasting" of the smaller tables to executor's worker nodes occurs to improve performance as well. You probably need not set any limit for Broadcasting, but you could set this explicitly, but may take is this is not required, based on what I observe.